# Old AMD Linux Drivers Cannot Be Downloaded From AMD

Tags: ati, catalyst

If you guys are in my boat, you may also be looking for older catalyst drivers for your card. The problem here is that while AMD does list SOME of the older drivers, half of them are not downloadable.

When you click the links on the AMD website for 12.1 - 12.4, your browser will either get stuck in a pattern of freezing and loading, you will download an unusable .bin file for reason, or you will get a page full of gibberish.

Just wanted you all to know, if you don't.

Since this is "Ask" Ubuntu, I need to ask if anyone of you fine folk know where to download old drivers. If you know of a website of have them yourself, PLEASE respond.

So far I have found this site, which looks a bit less legit than I would like, but hey, the word "school" is in the link, so it must be trustworthy, right? Maybe not if it is an American site...

http://****.ru/Soft/_Drivers/ATI/Linux/

Also, I am downloading three right now, and the projected download time is about 2 hours. So, you have that.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: OK, the download speed just shot up and I'm looking at an acceptable 80-110 KB/sec. I will let you all know if these are legitimate files, or if its a virus or kiddie porn or NSA tracking files. Either way, the driver sizes on that site match the sizes from AMD's, so I think these are actually the droids I'm looking for.

Comment: The official Ubuntu site for old releases (http://old-releases.ubuntu.com) is the right place you should start up with.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to download 12.1-12.4 from the [previous releases page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous?os=Linux%20x86) just fine with DownThemAll.

[image]

**Full links:**

```
http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64.run
http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-2-x86.x86_64.run
http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-3-x86.x86_64.run
http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.zip
```

Could you try again? May be it was just a hiccup on AMDs servers that they fixed in the mean time.